# Simpler or more functional way of chaining objects in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have created a helper method `buildChain` which essentially creates a 
chain of objects given that they implement the interface `IChain<T>` 
and set the contracts `next` member

**The Code**

```
interface Chain<T> {
    var next: T?

    operator fun plus(next: T): T?
}

fun <T : Chain<T>> buildChain(first: T, vararg members: T): T {
    var next: T? = null
    members.forEachIndexed { i, t ->
        if (i == 0) {
            next = first + t
        } else {
            next = next?.run { this + t }
        }
    }
    return first
}
```

**Implementation example**

```
data class Person(val name: String) : Chain<Person> {
    override var next: Person? = null

    override fun plus(next: Person): Person? {
        this.next = next
        return next
    }
}

fun createPersonChain()
        = buildChain(Person("Bob"), Person("Bitzy"), Person("Blitzy"))
```

**Implementaion output example**

```
@JvmStatic fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var first = createPersonChain()
    // first.name = "Bob"
    // first.next.name = "Bitzy"
    // first.next.next.name = "Blitzy"
 }
```

Is there a `functional` or `simpler` way for acheiving the `code` above keeping the implementaion usage the same?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A functional [idiom **fold**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)) suits your needs well: it takes an initial item and then iterates over the other items, maintaining an accumulated value, which is updated on each item being processed with the function you provide.

In Kotlin, it is [`fold` extension function](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/fold.html) for `Iterable`, `Sequence` or `Array`.

You can use it in the following way:

```
fun <T : Chain<T>> buildChain(first: T, vararg members: T): T {
    members.fold(first as T?) { acc, i -> acc?.let { it + i } }
    return first
}
```

Here `first as T?` cast is needed for the accumulator type to be inferred as nullable `T?`, because `plus` in your `Chain<T>` returns nullable value (by the way, is it necessary?).

You can also use [`foldRight`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/fold-right.html), which just iterates in the opposite order:

```
fun <T : Chain<T>> buildChain(first: T, vararg members: T): T? =
        (listOf(first) + members)
            .foldRight(null as T?) { i, acc -> acc?.let { i + acc }; i }
```

And there are [`reduce`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/reduce.html) and [`reduceRight`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/reduce-right.html) with similar semantics but using the first and the last item respectively for the accumulator's initial value. Here's the example with `reduceRight`:

```
fun <T : Chain<T>> buildChain(first: T, vararg members: T): T? =
        (listOf(first) + members).reduceRight { i, acc -> i.apply { plus(acc) } }
```

Comment: Thanks hotkey works like a charm, funny thing is I just learned the fold function throughout today and didn't realize it could be used in combination with the chaining code

Answer (score 3):

Try `apply{}`. In the `{}` block pass your methods separated with ';'

```
Object().apply{ method1(); signUp(user) }
```